# Exporting Order Info

Tags: square-connect

We use Square POS in our cafe currently. I'm trying to analyze and track my employees upselling. I want to cleanly track how many orders contain a specific item or category. I can kind of get there using a custom report, but I end up still doing some math to get the data I want. Because I'm a programmer I went to the API to pull data directly. I'm a little shocked to see I can't connect a transaction to an order. Am I missing something? It seems like I should be able to use the API to get a list of transactions by date and then get the associated items in the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need to use the [List Payments](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#get-payments) endpoint to view summary information (including itemization) for all payments taken on your Square account. Furthermore, you can use the begin_time and end_time parameters to narrow your search to a specific time frame.